# Solve for $x$,$y$ and $z$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve:

$$x^2+xy+y^2=7$$
 $$y^2+yz+z^2=19$$
 $$z^2+zx+x^2=3$$

I subtracted second equation from first and got $$(x-z)(x+y+z)=-12$$

Similarly I got $$(y-x)(x+y+z)=16$$
and $$(z-y)(x+y+z)=-4$$.

But I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: I think the third one is $(z-y)(x+y+z)$

Comment: If you want solutions in $\mathbb N$, the RHS of third equation must be 13 and solutions are (x, y, z)=(1, 2, 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means $(z-x)/12=(y-x)/16=(y-z)/4$
Multiply each side by 48
$4z-4x=3y-3x=12y-12z$
$4z-4x=3y-3x$ from this one $4z-3y=x$

Let's change the $x$ with  $4z-3y$ on $x^2+xy+y^2=7$
And this becomes $16z^2-20zy+7y^2=7$ and $z^2+zy+y^2=3$
$$20zy=16z^2+7y^2-7=20z^2+20y^2-60$$
From this $4z^2-27y^2=53$(lets call this (1))
$16z^2-20zy+7y^2+20z^2+20zy+20y^2=67$
From this $36z^2+27y^2=67$ (lets call it(2)

From (1) and (2) $40z^2=120$
$z^2 =3$ $z=\sqrt3$ or $z=-\sqrt3$

For $z=\sqrt3$

$y=-\sqrt3$ or $y=0$

For $y=-\sqrt3$
 $x=(\sqrt3+\sqrt43)/2$
$x=(\sqrt3-\sqrt43)/2$

For $y=0$
$x^2=7$    $x=\sqrt7$ or $ x=-\sqrt7$

And for $z=-\sqrt3$
$x$ and $y$ is similar to above

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, $x+y+z\neq 0,$ so divide the equations to get $y$ in terms of $x$ and $z$, then plug that expression for $y$ back into $x^2+xy+y^2=7$, which will become in terms of $x,z,$ then solve the system of equations with $z^2+zx+x^2=3$

Answer (score 0):

Divide pairwise by the sum of the three solutions, to get a linear $3×3$ system, which is easily soluble.

Answer (score 0):

The hint.

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$, where $v^2$ can be negative, and $xyz=w^3$.

Thus, $$29=\sum_{cyc}(x^2+xy+y^2)=\sum_{cyc}(2x^2+xy)=2(9u^2-6v^2)+3v^2=9(2u^2-v^2).$$
Also, $$211=\sum_{cyc}(x^2+xy+y^2)(x^2+xz+z^2)=17(3u^4-2u^2v^2+v^4),$$ which gives
$$(u^2,v^2)=\left(\frac{13}{9},-\frac{1}{3}\right)$$ or
$$(u^2,v^2)=\left(\frac{16}{9},\frac{1}{3}\right).$$
Also, $$399=\prod_{cyc}(x^2+xy+y^2)=27(3u^2v^4-u^3w^3-v^6),$$
which gives a possibility to find a value of $w^3$ (four cases) and

by the Viete's theorem we can get four cubic equations.

I got the following answer:
$$\left\{(1,-3,-2),(-1,3,2),\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt{13}},-\frac{11}{\sqrt{13}},-\frac{7}{\sqrt{13}}\right),\left(-\frac{5}{\sqrt{13}},\frac{11}{\sqrt{13}},\frac{7}{\sqrt{13}}\right)\right\}$$